# Error defining and initializing multidimensional array

Tags: c++, initialization, multidimensional-array, definition

I get error in compilation with the following definition.

```
int  matrix[ ][ ] = { { 1, 2, 3}, {4,5,6} };

char str[ ][ ] = { "abc", "fgh" };
```

Why is the compiler complaining missing subscript and too many initializers.

Answer (score 8):

If an array is defined as `int arr[ ROWS ][ COLS ];` then any array notation `arr[ i ][ j ]` can be translated to pointer notation as

```
*( arr + i * COLS + j )
```

**Observe that the expression requires only COLS, it does not require ROWS.** So, the array
definition can be written equivalently as

```
int arr [][ COLS ];
```

But, missing the second dimension is not acceptable.

Further understanding can be achieved by following the three examples given below.
In all three examples, the same array notation `arr[ 2 ][ 3 ]` is translated to pointer
notation.

- Between A and B, ROWS is same but COLS is different; result = pointer notation
  is different.
- Between A and C, ROWS is different but COLS is same; result = pointer notation is same.

Examples:

```
A. int arr[ 4 ][ 7 ];      arr[2][3] = arr + 2 * 7 + 3 = arr + 17
B. int arr[ 4 ][ 5 ];      arr[2][3] = arr + 2 * 5 + 3 = arr + 13
C. int arr[ 6 ][ 7 ];      arr[2][3] = arr + 2 * 7 + 3 = arr + 17
```

Answer (score 7):

When you declare a multi-dimensional array, you must explicitly define the size of all but the last dimension.  Otherwise, the compiler won't know how to find a given value in the array.

edit: read my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309756/declaring-an-array-in-c-without-giving-size/3310690#3310690)

Comment: any idea why can't the compiler calculate the size by counting the number of elements from the initializer list before allocating.

Comment: I explain it in the other post that I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
include <string>
```

and

```
string str[] = { "abc", "fgh" };
```

Comment: This might need a `"` after `"abc,` and a `;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`int  matrix[2][3] = { { 1, 2, 3}, {4,5,6} };

char str[2][4] = { "abc", "fgh" };`
the first declaration  will make 2d int array has 2 rows with 3 col.
the second will make 2d char array with 2 rows and 4 col.
the 4th element in each row in the char array is the `NULL` char