# Pass 2D array to function by reference

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reference

So in my main function I'm creating a 2D array:

```
int dataDim = 100;
float inData[2][dataDim];
```

I want to pass it to a function where I will be able to fill it up with data. How to pass it in a manner that I will be able to fill it up directly? Maybe

```
function(float** array)
```

and then accessing `array[0][0]` probably doesn't work? Strange how I can't find any quick example about this.

Comment: There is this great tool: http://www.ideone.com

Comment: @iccthedral and this was a great spam.

Comment: Do i need to pass the array as function(&array) ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/passing-2d-arrays

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in C, multidimensional arrays' sizes must be known to pass as such, although some sizes may be omitted, if you like.

**Exact**

```
void function(float array[][100]); 
void function(float (*array)[100]);
```

**Syntactically Valid**

Although the compiler may legally ignore the size `2`.

```
void function(float array[2][100]);
```

Comment: And also `void function(float (*array)[100])`