# Passing a "normal" 2d array to function as **

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-allocation

I want to do this but it doesn't work. Is it possible to do it or do I have to declare A as double pointer float**? Note that I need an universal function for various array dimensions so I can't change the function arguments.

```
void func(float** arr, int x, int y){
    //access to arr[0][0] for e.g. causes SEGFAULT
}
...
float A[2][2]={{1,0},{0,1}};
func(A, 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass 2D array to function you need to know at least element count in 2nd dimension at compilation time.

```
void func(float arr[][2], int n)
```

If you don't know the size of array at compile time there isn't much you can do except:

```
void func(float *arr, int n, int m)
{
    // getting arr[i][j] with arr[i*m + j]
}

float A[2][2]={{1,0},{0,1}};
func(&A[0][0], 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the declaration of `func()` to:

```
void func(float arr[2][2], int x, int y)
{
}
```

For futher reading see this answer: [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/passing-2d-arrays)

Comment: I need an universal function and I don't know what the arr size will be. That's why I have x and y.

Comment: @PrimožKralj I'd suggest emulating a 2D array using a 1D [row*column] array then, and using function calls for lookups. You can't do what you want to do in C.

Answer (score 1):

A 2d array is NOT equivalent to `**`. As a rule, you can strip off one "layer" of indirection any replace it with `[]`. Thus something like `float *A[]` is equivalent to `float **A`. Note you can also only have one array dimension having undefined size; thus `float[2][]` is ok, while `float[][]` is not.

You'll need to change your func to something like `void func(float *arr[2], ...)` or `void func(float arr[2][], ...)`.

Comment: Please see my edit - I don't know what array dimensions will be.

Answer (score 1):

If generality is your concern, you need to make it work like this:

```
 void func(int** arr, int x, int y)
{
}

int main()
{
  int rows, cols, i;
  int **arr;

  arr = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
  for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
  {
    arr[i] = (int*)malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
  }
  arr[0][0]=1;arr[1][0]=0;arr[0][1]=0;arr[0][1]=1;
  func(arr, rows, cols);

  for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
  {
    free(arr[i]);
  }
  free(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a modern C compiler, starting with C99, you may simply do

```
void func(size_t x, size_t y, float arr[x][y]) {
 // something using arr[i][j] naturally
}
```

The only restriction is that the sizes must come *before* they are used in the parameter list.

On the call side you then can use something like the following to avoid allocating a dynamic matrix as `auto` variable:

```
float (*A)[x0] = malloc(sizeof(float[x0][y0]);
...
func(x0, y0, A);
...
free(A)
```