# Passing a 2d-array to a function in C

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

Note I'm using C not C++.  I'm working on a program that will take a 2d-array and count the numbers of non-spaces in a subarray.  Such as `lines[0][i]` <-- iterating over `line[0][0] - line[0][n]`.  However, I'm having difficulty getting the function to accept the 2d-array.

Here is my code:

```
pScore[0]=letters(pLines, 0);
```

This is the actual function. `pScore[]` is another array, but a 1d one.  `pLines` is a 4 by 200 2d-array.

```
 int letters(char line[][], int row)
 {
     int i = 0;
     int n = n;
     int results = 0;

     for( i = 0; i < (sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0])); i++ )
     {
         if( !isspace(line[row][i]) )
             results++;
     }

     return results;
 }
```

When I do this it gives me "formal parameter number 1 is not complete".   If I remove the second `[]` from it, the code runs but gives the worng number of non-space characters.

Comment: Why are you trying to iterate by number of rows instead of number of columns?

Comment: You need to show the declaration of `lines` before anyone can do anything but guess. If you have declared `lines` as say `char lines[maxr][maxc] = {{0}};`, then you probably need to function parameter passing lines to look like `int letters (char (*line)[], int row)`.

Comment: @MikeCAT I'm trying to count the number of non-space characters in that subarray.  Like:  pLines[0][0-199] <-- I want to see how many of those are a non-space character.

Answer (score 3):

Taking from the comments above, and your function parameter list:

```
int letters(char line[][], int row)
```

You violate one primary tenant of passing a 2D array to a function. Specifically, you must always provide the number of *columns* contained in the array. e.g.

```
int letters(char line[][5], int row)
```

`char line[][5]` is an appropriate parameter. However, whenever you pass an array as a function parameter, the *first level of indirection* is converted to a pointer. (you will often here this referred to as "*pointer-decay*", though that is a bit of a misnomer). Therefore a proper declaration that makes this clear is:

```
int letters(char (*line)[5], int row)
```

`line`, after conversion, is a *pointer-to-an-array* of `5-int`. While you can pass the array as `line[][5]`, that is not nearly as informative as `(*line)[5]`. Let me know if you have any questions.

---

**Numbers Instead of Characters**

It is hard to tell what is going on without seeing the remainder of your code. However, I suspect that you are confusing the *numerical value* and the *ASCII character value* for the contents of your array. (e.g. *character* `'0'` = *decimal* `48` (`0x30` (hex), `'1' = 49`, `'a' = 97`, etc..). See [**ASCIItable.com**](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense.  It is now taking my array, I think, but for some reason it is saying the contents of the array is a bunch of numbers rather than the user specified characters.  (Previous printf()s show the array is characters.)

Comment: See the addition to the answer. I suspect that you are confusing the *numerical value* and the *ASCII character value*.

Answer (score 2):

You you pass an array to a function it decays to a pointer. That means `char line[][]` should really by `char (*line)[SIZE_OF_SECOND_ARRAY]`.

It also means the `sizeof` trick will not work, as doing `sizeof` on the *pointer* `line` will just return the size of the pointer and not what it points to, you need to explicitly pass the size as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need tell function the number of columns of 2d array. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the following statement works with you

```
for( i = 0; i < (sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0])); i++ )
```

where `sizeof(line)` will be 4 or something like that depends on your platform because "line" is a pointer and you get the size of pointer itself.
Correct me if I am wrong.
In this case, you should pass column number as row's.

Comment: Your assumption on `line` being a pointer for which in turn the `sizeof`-operator return the size of a pointer is correct.