# Pass variable in form int[][] into method with type int**

Tags: c, pointers

I have a two dimensional array of integers and a function that retrieves a particular column from that two dimensional array. The function has an int** as a parameter. How can I create a int** to point to my int[][].

```
int* getColumn(int **matrix, int rows, int column, int columnNum)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    int mat[2][2];
    mat[0][0] = 1;
    mat[0][1] = 2;
    mat[1][0] = 3;
    mat[1][1] = 4;

    getColumn( ? , 2, 2, 1);
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to declare "mat" as a double pointer instead?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. You cannot create an `int**` to point at an `int[][]`.

Comment: If your compiler supports [VLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), then you can declare the function as `int *getColumn(int columnNum, int rows, int column, int matrix[rows][column])`.

Comment: Originally I declared "mat" as an int** however my professor said that using pointers in this manner was error prone. He suggested using a two dimensional array instead.

Comment: If there's a better way to retrieve a column from a  two dimensional array then that would also satisfy my question.

Comment: Can `getColumn` be changed or is that a provided function?

Comment: I know from experience that it's impossible to pass arrays this way.

Comment: I'm writing getColumn so it can be written in any manner.

Comment: See: [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c)

Comment: I believe that option 2 in the provided link suits my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no *easy* way to do it, because those are completely different types - one is a 2D array, and the other is a pointer to (presumably a 1D array of) pointers to (presumably 1D arrays of) ints.

This is the memory layout of an `int[2][2]` at let's say address 5678: (and assuming ints are one byte, which they're not on most real systems, but let's pretend)

```
Address  5678 5679 5680 5681
        +----+----+----+----+
        | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
        +----+----+----+----+
        ^ address of mat
```

This is the memory layout of one possible `int**` representing the same array:

```
Address  2345 2346 ... 3456 3457 ... 5682
        +----+----+...+----+----+...+----+----+
        | 1  | 2  |...| 3  | 4  |...|2345|3456|
        +----+----+...+----+----+...+----+----+
                                    ^ address of mat2
```

As you can see, they're not the same. The main difference is that with the `int**` representation each row is allowed to be at a completely different address, and "the matrix" is actually an array holding a pointer to each row

However, you *can* make an array of pointers to each row yourself:

```
int *rows[2] = {
    mat[0],
    mat[1]
};
getColumn(rows, 2, 2, 1);
```

but this gets complicated if your matrix isn't always the same size.

(The memory layout for this would be:

```
Address  5678 5679 5680 5681 ... 5700 5701
        +----+----+----+----+...+----+----+
        | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |...|5678|5680|
        +----+----+----+----+...+----+----+
        ^ address of mat        ^ address of rows
```

)

Comment: This is a great explanation. I have what I need now to solve my problem. Thank you!