# Printing command gives error in function

Tags: c, function

```
void print( matrix)
{
    printf("    0    1    2    3    4     5    6    7  \n"); /* printing the game board */
    printf("    -------------------------------------    \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%d|", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            printf(" %3c ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

so I defined this function in the compiler, ran the code and get the following error message for this line `printf(" %3c ",matrix[i][j]);`

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

I tried defining the `matrix` as int and as char value, but still same error

what I am trying to achieve by calling the function
[image]

one more thing is that the code itself without being a function works without a problem

calling the function:
first I defined

```
char playboard[8][8];
```

then filled the array with the symbol "~"

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
       {
          playboard[i][j] = '~';
       }
  }
```

then called the function print

```
print(playboard);
```

Comment: at `void print(matrix)` : you need type of `matrix`

Comment: C does not have a vector type. If this is compiled by a C++ compiler, change the tag!

Comment: @Olaf this is a C compiler

Comment: Unlikely. Please provide a [mcve] and **all** required information, including the compiler command line.

Comment: `void print(matrix)` is not C. It won't compile. There is probably a copy/paste problem here.

Comment: Please, *format out* your code, it's unreadable

Comment: @MichaelWalz How do I change it to fit into C? I came from Python and new to C

Comment: It depends how `print` is called and what type of variable is provided. Show the calling code and the relevant variable declarations.

Comment: [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3911400/669576)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
void print(char matrix[8][8])
{
    printf("    0    1    2    3    4     5    6    7\n"); /* printing the game board */
    printf("    -------------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%d|", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            printf(" %3c ", matrix[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Michael answer you should pass sizes of array to the function to make it portable. Take a look at this simple example using sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print(size_t rows, size_t cols, char matrix[rows][cols])
{
    printf("    0    1    2    3    4     5    6    7\n"); /* printing the game board */
    printf("    -------------------------------------\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        printf("%zu|", i);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            printf(" %3c ", matrix[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    char playboard[8][8];

    memset(playboard, 0x7E, sizeof(playboard));

    print(sizeof(playboard[8]), sizeof(playboard[0])/sizeof(playboard[0][0]), playboard);
}
```

Comment: I am still a beginner when it comes to C, didn't totally get everything, but the first answer works perfectly
thank you nonetheless

Comment: I know it, and @MichaelWalz answer was perfect. Mine is only to add some details.