# C-Pass a matrix to function without non-constant column value

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array

i want to pass a matrix to a function in C. If i want to make the dimension of the matrix to be non-constant (eg. let the user insert by keyboard the NxM dimension) i have no problems in this. However when i try to pass this to a function i encounter some problems:

-The number of column MUST be specified in the header of the function(s) who have a matrix as parameter. If i omit this value i get:

> error: array type has incomplete element type ‘int[]’  void
>   trasposeMatrix(int M[][],int n,int m)
>                           esercizi.c:282:25: note: declaration of ‘M’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the
>   first

with this function:

```
void trasposeMatrix(int M[][],int n,int m)
{
    int temp=0;
    int M2[n][m];

    printf("La matrice prima della trasposizione è: \n");
    printMatrix(M,3,3);

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            M2[i][j]=M[j][i];
        }
    }

    printf("La matrice dopo la trasposizione è: \n");
    printMatrix(M2,3,3);
}
```

with this call:

```
trasposeMatrix(M,3,3);
```

-This value MUST be constant, otherwise if i put a parameter as value in those brackets i get this error:

> esercizi.c: At top level: esercizi.c:282:29: error: ‘m’ undeclared
>   here (not in a function)  void trasposeMatrix(int M[][m],int n,int m)

with the same call and this code:

```
void trasposeMatrix(int M[][m],int n,int m)
{
    int temp=0;
    int M2[n][m];

    printf("La matrice prima della trasposizione è: \n");
    printMatrix(M,3,3);

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            M2[i][j]=M[j][i];
        }
    }

    printf("La matrice dopo la trasposizione è: \n");
    printMatrix(M2,3,3);
}
```

This can be "avoided" using constants to specify the matrix dimensions. However i don't like this kind of "constraint". Finally what if i would print a matrix via a function: what should i write in the function header if the dimesion is variable?? 
The function i wrote to print a matrix works well for a 3x3 matrix but what to do for 2x2 matrices and for 3x4. Maybe you got the point

Note: this things do not happen with arrays where i just write a header like:
`void printArray(int a[], int dimension){}` and this works. I don't know why. Maybe is a design behaviour of C decided by his inventor, but i hope isn't because is so tediuos

Note 2: :) i'm using linux mint with gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
but with VS for Win10 i even cannot put a variable as dimension of an array :(

I'm so sorry for the very long message, but i hope to get an answer. Thanks for reading

Comment: Write the dimensions first in the argument list: ``void transposeMatrix(int r, int c, int M[r][c])`` and so on. You seem to list columns before rows in your argument list; decide on an order and stick with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Note that the English spelling of the function would usually be `transposeMatrix` rather than `trasposeMatrix`.  You're consistent so it isn't a major problem, but… . (Incidentally, I mentioned possible problems with the order of the dimension arguments — that was a mistake on my part, induced by trying to see what was going on in your code while viewing it on a cell phone.  Your code is fine on that point.)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the array dimensions before the array in the function call.  This feature was added to C99 (and is in C11 and C18, therefore); it is not part of standard C++.  That means there are some compilers 'out there' that still don't support the notation.

You have:

```
void trasposeMatrix(int M[][m],int n,int m)
{
```

You need:

```
void trasposeMatrix(int n, int m, int M[n][m])
{
```

Or perhaps:

```
void trasposeMatrix(int n, int m, int M[][m])
{
```

but I think the previous version with both dimensions specified is clearer about the intent.

In the function declarations (in a header, for example), you can use the definition notation (where the `extern` is optional and occasionally contentious — there are those who don't like it, and those who do, such as me):

```
extern void trasposeMatrix(int n, int m, int M[n][m]);
```

or you can go eccentric and use:

```
extern void trasposeMatrix(int n, int m, int M[*][*]);
```

That tells the compiler that the dimensions of the matrix will be determined at runtime, but doesn't indicate where they come from.  I prefer the 'copy of the definition' version because the intent is clearer.  You can't use the `*` notation in the function definition.

If you want to find out 'all about it', you could go read the standard — C11 [§6.7.6.2 Array declarators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2) and [§6.7.6.2 Function declarators (including prototypes)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3) — but the language is hard to parse.

Answer (score 0):

"Declaration of ‘M’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first"

This tells you that you need to specify a value in the first bracket:

M[]<- can be empty [x]<-cant be empty and has to be constant.

If you don't want to get "constraint" then use malloc and free for allocating dynamic memory at runtime.

Comment: You seem to be saying that `void trasposeMatrix(int M[X][], int n, int m){ … }` would be OK.  Sadly, the compiler would beg to disagree with you.  You must specify a dimension for all but the first of the dimensions, so `void trasposeMatrix(int M[][X], int n, int m){ … }` would be OK, but not what you seem to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

> array type has incomplete element type ‘int[]’

To declare an array the compiler needs to know how big the array elements are.

Imagine `int arr[2][];` How big the array elements are? The compiler needs to know how many bytes to "jump" between `&arr[0]` and `&arr[1]`. How to increment a pointer to `arr`?

Imagine `int (*arr)[2];` This is a pointer to array of 2 ints. Between `&arr[0]` and `&arr[1]` are 2 integers: `arr[0][0]` and `arr[0][1]` exactly. So the compiler knows that `&arr[1]` is at position `(uintptr_t)(void*)&arr[0] + 2 * sizeof(int)`.

Variable length array declarations (`int M[]`) and all array declarations (`int M[5]`) "are adjusted" ("are equal to") to a pointer to the types (`int *M`) inside function parameter list ([see C11 6.7.6.3p7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7)). What that means is that each time you write `void func(int a[500*1000*320100])` it's the same as `void func(int *a)`.

You can't declare `int *(a[]);` a pointer to array to unknown number of elements. Array elements need to be complete type. So the compilers knows how much memory to reserve for them.

> error: ‘m’ undeclared here

Imagine a function like this:

```
int main() {
  int m[i];
  int i = 5;
}
```

You will get `i undeclared here`. Well, now imagine a function like:

```
int func(
  int m[i],
  int i
) {}
```

You will get the same error, but in function parameter list. It's the same, the variable needs to be declared before it's use.