# Segmentation fault after passing a matrix to a function

Tags: c, square

My program needs to check if the input matrix is a [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square).

It is almost done, but I have a problem with fuction. I am not sure why but it return wrong values. I need function to return 1 if square is magic and to return 0 if square isn´t magic. I am getting weird output and segmentation fault.

example of input:

```
3 - size of square, square: 
8 1 6
3 5 7
4 9 2
```

example of output
(function return 1 because square is magic)
printed on screen is Square is magic.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_magic(int m[][size], size_t size)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(size_t col = 0; col < size; col++)
    {
        sum += m[col];
    }

    for(size_t row = 1; row < size; row++)
    {
        int psum = 0;
        for(size_t col = 0; col < size; col++)
        {
            psum += m[col + row * size];
        }
        if(psum != sum) return 0;
    }

    for(size_t col = 0; col < size; col++)
    {
        int psum = 0;
        for(size_t row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            psum += m[col + row * size];
        }
        if(psum != sum) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


int main()
{
      int size,row,column;
      scanf("%d",&size);
      int *matrix
      matrix = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
            for (row = 0; row < size; row++)
                  matrix[row] = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));


      for (row = 0; row < size; row++)
             for (column = 0; column < size; column++)
                   scanf("%d ", &matrix[row][column]);


       if(is_magic(matrix, size))
      {
            printf("Magic square");
      }
      else
      {
            printf("Not magic square");
      }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int matrix[size][size]` is not `int ** matrix`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c)

Comment: First you need to explain what the magic square is

Comment: @P__J__: sum of elements in each row, column or diagonal must be equal (15 in this case). It doesn't seem it will work, but at least passing the matrix correctly will allow OP to debug.

Comment: @Groo The answer may be a dupe, but not the question

Comment: @P__J__ I think that's irrelevant as the author gets set faults and his magic number calculation logic is up to them

Comment: @John: the problem OP is having is because you cannot pass a 2d array into a function this way.

Comment: @Groo I've provided an answer to that already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two dimensional array is just the continuous chink of memory. If the array has same number of columns and rows the order of storing them is not important in this case.

```
int is_magic(int *m, size_t size)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(size_t col = 0; col < size; col++)
    {
        sum += m[col];
    }

    for(size_t row = 1; row < size; row++)
    {
        int psum = 0;
        for(size_t col = 0; col < size; col++)
        {
            psum += m[col + row * size];
        }
        if(psum != sum) return 0;
    }

    for(size_t col = 0; col < size; col++)
    {
        int psum = 0;
        for(size_t row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            psum += m[col + row * size];
        }
        if(psum != sum) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int m[3][3] = 
{
    {8, 1, 6},
    {3, 5, 7},
    {4, 9, 2},
};

int m1[3][3] = 
{
    {8, 1, 6},
    {3, 9, 7},
    {4, 9, 2},
};


int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", is_magic(m,3));
    printf("%d\n", is_magic(m1,3));

    return 0;
}
```

Working example: https://ideone.com/P4C3H2

Comment: Are you sure row should start from 1 in here `for(size_t row = 1; row < size; row++)` ?

Comment: yes ,I do not need to calculate the first one (the one with index 0) as it was already done in the previous loop.

Comment: You misspelled chunk in the answer (:

Comment: I updated code but now I am getting compilation error, i think it has something to do with allocating memory for 2d array doesn´t it?

Comment: @Dudo what compilation problem?

Comment: error: ‘size’ undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean ‘size_t’?
 int is_magic(int m[][size], size_t size)
                      ^~~~
                      size_t
 In function ‘main’:
 error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘matrix’
       matrix = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
       ^~~~~~
error: ‘matrix’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘main’?
       matrix = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
       ^~~~~~
       main

Comment: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
        if(is_magic(matrix, size))
                    ^~~~~~

Comment: I´ve replaced some lines but I do still get error and in Bigger test with more numbers than just 3 I get that function returned 0 even when square was magic

Comment: Do not change my function declaration. You are amending it - but you do not know what you are doing. Leave it as it is.  `int is_magic(int *m, size_t size)` not anything else. Do not mix with another solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the signature of the is_magic function. You need to pass in a two dimensional array to it;

```
int is_magic(int **matrix,int size);
```

Here you are passing a pointer to an int pointer.

What you need is to pass a two dimensional array as follows:

```
int is_magic(int matrix[][size], int size);
```

Make sure to use a C99 compliant compiler.

Quick side note, you may or not need to reverse the order of the arguments for the is_magic function.

You actually need to reverse the order of the parameters as follows to comply with the function call order of arguments.

```
int is_magic(int size, int matrix[][size]);
```

Answer (score -2):

The call of `is_magic`should be

`flag = is_magic(matrix,size);`

as this is consistent with your function definition.

Answer (score -3):

Try the following :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int is_magic(int **matrix,int size)
{
int sum, sum1, sum2;
int row, column = 0;
//For diagonal elements
sum = 0;
for (row = 0; row < size; row++)
{
    for (column = 0; column < size; column++)
    {
        if (row == column)
            sum = sum + matrix[row][column];
    }
}

//For Rows
for (row = 0; row < size; row++)
{
    sum1 = 0;
    for (column = 0; column < size; column++)
    {
        sum1 = sum1 + matrix[row][column];
    }
    if (sum == sum1)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        return 0;
        break;
    }
}

//For Columns
for (row = 0; row < size; row++)
{
    sum2 = 0;
    for (column = 0; column < size; column++)
    {
        sum2 = sum2 + matrix[column][row];
    }
    if (sum == sum2)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        return 0;
        break;
    }
}
}


int main()
{
int size;
scanf("%d",&size);
int matrix[size][size];
int row=0, column = 0;
int flag = 0;

for (row = 0; row < size; row++)
{
    for (column = 0; column < size; column++)
        scanf("%d", &matrix[row][column]);
    printf("%d\n", matrix[row][column]);
}

flag = is_magic(size,matrix);
if (flag == 1)
    printf("1");
else
    printf("0");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not working mate, compiles but it has random no´s inside

Comment: "Try this" is not an answer. You should at a minimum explain what you changed in the code and why it solves the problem.