# Iterating over a 2D array (int **) causes segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int **arr, int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++) {
            printf("%d\n", arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int arr[3][3] = {
        {11, 12, 13},
        {21, 22, 23},
        {31, 32, 33},
    };
    func((int**)arr, 3);
}
```

In this code I'm trying to pass a 2D array to another function and have the second function print out all it's values. I've chosen to specify the array as a `int **` in the signature of the function (loosely following the [second method specified in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3912959/2138219)).

When I run this code I expect it to be able to print out all the items, but instead it seg faults and I'm not sure why. I've tried debugging it, but gdb points me  to the `printf`'s array access in the `func` function, but I already suspected that's the cause. There is obviously a discrepency between what I think the memory looks like and how i'm trying to access it and how it's actaully being accessed (or what's being accessed).

Comment: Why are you casting the argument to `func`? You're passing in the incorrect type. Casting can't fix that.

Comment: @tadman I'm compiling with Wall and I get `-Wincompatible-pointer-types` otherwise. `note: expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int (*)[3]'`

Comment: Yes, that's what you've defined. An array of `int[3]`, not an array of `int*`. This is a huge difference. One is just three elements, the other is a pointer.

Comment: @tadman Is my approach wrong then? I can't remove the 3's - it complains. Should I use malloc here?

Comment: A pointer to a pointer to `int` is not a 2d array.

Comment: `int[3][3]` and `int**` are not inter-compatible. You might want to switch this to a single `3*3`-sized array as honestly multidimensional arrays in C are an utter nightmare, not only from a code perspective but also from how they require *N+1* pointers instead of 1 and can scatter your data all over the heap.

Comment: @Swordfish What would be the correct approach based on what I'm trying to do? My underlying question, that I've omitted for the sake of simplicity here, has to go with passing a 2D array via a struct to another thread and then accessing elements on it. I figured if I can figure out how to access things on an `int **` I would solve that problem too.

Comment: @tadman Good to know. I'm lacking the experience in C to know the best approach and figured pointer to a pointer was the best approach. I'll switch to a single 3*3 array. Thanks

Comment: By comparison C++ has far better support for this sort of thing, but C, being much more low-level, expects you to to organize things a certain way or deal with the complexity yourself. `int[3][3]` has a memory layout similar to `int[3*3]`, there's no intermediate pointers. It's not equivalent to `int**`.

Comment: @tadman *but also from how they require N+1 pointers instead of 1 and can scatter your data all over the heap.* – what you're describing isn't a 2d-array either.

Comment: @tadman i'd call a pointer to an array of pointers to array a jagged array.

Comment: @Swordfish Like everything in C it's got a lot of sharp edges.

Comment: @tadman *but an array of arrays* – an array of arrays is a 2d-array (`T foo[COLUMNS][ROWS]`) but a pointer to one or more pointers to `T` is something different. Sorry for being that picky but i can't stand it when people mix those things up.

Comment: @Swordfish That's a much better explanation.

Comment: @Swordfish so if I understand you correctly. You're saying [[0, 1], [2, 3]] is a 2d array, but [0x1230, 0x1238], where 0x1230 contains [0, 1] and same for 0x1238, is something different. Is my understanding of this correct? The big difference being 2d array is a contiguous block of memory, but a pointer to a pointer of T could be anywhere in memory.

Comment: @tadman multidimensional arrays do not require `N+1` pointers and also allocate the data contiguously. I get what you mean, but just not the right term.

Comment: `func(int **arr, int s)` --> `func(int arr[][3], int s)`

Comment: @chux One chux for the rescue ;) one more thing to say: `func(int arr[][3], int s)` is exactly the same as `func(int *arr[3], int s)`.

Comment: Might be helpful: [How to Read C Declarations](https://parrt.cs.usfca.edu/doc/how-to-read-C-declarations.html) and [cdecl: C gibberish ↔ English](https://cdecl.org/)

Comment: Try `void func(int s, int arr[s][s]) {`  (C99)

Comment: @chux Thanks for the suggestion, but I did use that but it doesn't fit in my real world situation. my real situation was on in which I'm passing a 2d array to a thread via a struct. I didn't know how to pass an actual arr[s][s] type via a struct or how to case a (int **) back into a arr[s][s] without the compiler complaining, so I figured a (int **) was my best bet. I've followed the advice given here and used a 1d array of size s*s and that has worked perfectly for my situation.

Comment: "I didn't know how to pass an actual `arr[s][s]` type" --> My suggest was not to _pass_  a `arr[s][s]`, but to use `arr[s][s]` as the receiving parameter.  Just call as `func(3, arr)`.  Better, post a more complete example of what your need.

Comment: You can define the array as a field of your struct.  this is a live test of this approach: https://https://segfault.stensal.com/a/KTH9up3OKUzNsHpd