# Using a char matrix as a parameter to a function

Tags: c

I am trying to pass a char matrix as a parameter to another function but the programme keeps stopping, without giving me any error.
I have read the matrix from a file which contains the following (each value on different line):
6
AFAA26
7A4255
1C80B6
2C158F
DA8204
5A408A

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void read(char s[100][100],int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%s\n",s[i]);
}

int main()
{
  random();
  FILE *fp=fopen("p1","r");
  int n,i,j;
  fscanf(fp,"%d",&n);
  char s[20][10];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      fscanf(fp,"%s",&s[i]);
  fclose (fp);
  read(s,n);
  return 0;
}
```

note: by writing "`for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%s\n",s[i]);`" in the main function it reads me correctly the values from the file.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting any warning from you compiler?

Comment: Don't name your function `read`.  There's already a standard POSIX function called `read`.  The irony being that your `read` function doesn't actually read anything from.

Comment: when `read` tries to access `s[7]`, how are you expecting the compiler to know where that string begins? The `read` function has no idea that each string in `s` is 10 characters long.

Answer (score 3):

Your sizes from the declared array and the parameter do not match.

You can either declare the same dimensions, perhaps using a `#define` to avoid duplication, or have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c) for other (maybe better) alternatives.