# Passing Multidimensional Arrays into a Function

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to be able to pass a 2D array into the scanning function after scanning for the size of the array. Everywhere I've looked has told me that you can't pass 2D arrays without dimensions into a function, but I have no clue any other way to do it.

````
void scan_arrays (int *array, int row, int column);

int main (void){

  int row;
  int column;

  printf("Enter sizes: ");
  scanf("%d %d",&row,&column);


  int firstarray[row][column];
  int secondarray[row][column];

  printf("Enter array 1 elements:\n");
  scan_arrays(&firstarray,row,column);

  printf("Enter array 2 elements:\n");
  scan_arrays(&secondarray,row,column);

  for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
      printf("%d ",firstarray[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
      printf("%d ",secondarray[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}

void scan_arrays (int *array, int row, int column){

  for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
      scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

}```
I've only been coding for a couple of months.
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Hi Dan, your closing comment mentions you're new to programming.  I thought you may find [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) informative.  It does not negate the answer.  I hope it improves your undertanding.  The answer to your question works because it's evaluated at _compile time_.  During _run time_, the order of evaluation of your function's parameters isn't guaranteed as specified.  I've had unexpected results in my own code because I didn't fully understand this earlier.

Answer (score 5):

The function should be declared this way:

```
void scan_arrays (int row, int column, int array[row][column]);
```

and likewise for the first line of the function definition.  The `row` and `column` parameters have to come first so that they are in scope for their usage in the `array` parameter.   The `row` in the array dimension is technically redundant but an easy way for the code to self-document.

The function would be called like this:

```
scan_arrays(row, column, firstarray)
```

and the rest of your code can remain unchanged.

---

It would be a good idea to do some validation of the user input before defining the arrays: it will cause trouble if they enter garbage, `0`, negative numbers, or large numbers that cause stack overflow.  The latter problem can be avoided with dynamic allocation:

```
int (*firstarray)[column] = malloc( sizeof(int[row][column]) );
if ( firstarray == NULL )
    // ...error handling
```

and the code that uses `firstarray` can remain unchanged.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Can't believe it was something so simple.