# How do I pass a 2 dimensional array as an argument?

Tags: c

```
void Printarr(int col, int **arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < col; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

this is function for printing array.

```
int main(){
    int col = 0;
    scanf("%d", &col);
    int abc[col][col];
    for(int i = 0; i < col; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            abc[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
```

and I want to print array abc.

```
Printarr(col, abc);
```

the error is when it run this code **Printarr(col, abc);**

```
No matching function for call to 'Printarr'
```

Comment: You can't. C++ does not work this way. This is not even valid C or C++, but relies on your compiler's custom extension to the C++ standard. If this was submitted as a homework assignment, most professors will fail it, for not being valid C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Note that a *bona fide* 2D array is an array of arrays, not an array of pointers, thus a corresponding function parameter must be a pointer to a (correct-length) array, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @walnut - The question was tagged C++ when Sam commented.  Sam's comment is correct in C++ - which has never supported VLAs.   VLAs are also optional in C11.

Comment: @walnut - Given that a number of C++ compilers support VLAs as a non-standard extension, it is understandable that the OP tagged the code as C++.   Passing a 2D array to a function expecting a pointer to pointer is not valid in either C or C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Printarr(int col, int arr[][col]){
    for(int i = 0; i < col; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int col = 10;
    int abc[col][col];
    for(int i = 0; i < col; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            abc[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    Printarr(col,abc);
    return 0;
}
```

Your function argument is a pointer to a pointer but you only give it a normal pointer.