# I m trying to make a function that checks if a matrix is lower triangular or not but I have a problem running it, it says n and int m are not declared

Tags: c, function, matrix

I m trying to make a function that checks if a matrix is lower triangular or not but I have a problem running it, it says n and int m are not declared

```
int lower_mat(int mat[n][m],int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;
    int count=0;
    if (n==m)
    {
        for ( i = 0; i <n; i++)
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                if( i < j )
                {

                    if (mat[i][j]!=0)
                    {

                        return -1;
                    }
                }


            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `int lower_mat(int n, int m, int mat[n][m])` ?

Comment: This question is answered very well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c by @Bart van Ingen Schenau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declaration of `int m` and `int n` should come first and then you should use them , you should say `int lower_mat(int n, int m, int mat[n][m])` instead of `int lower_mat(int mat[n][m],int n, int m)`.