# the sum of an hourglass in C (2D array)

Tags: c, gcc, arduino

Print the largest (maximum) hourglass sum found in arr :

```
-1 -1  0 -9 -2 -2
-2 -1 -6 -8 -2 -5
-1 -1 -1 -2 -3 -4
-1 -9 -2 -4 -4 -5
-7 -3 -3 -2 -9 -9
-1 -3 -1 -2 -4 -5
```

```
int hourglassSum(int arr_rows, int arr_columns, int** arr) {
    int max=0;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<arr_rows-2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<arr_columns-2;j++){
          int sum=arr[i][j]+arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j+2]+arr[i+1][j+1]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2];
           if(sum>=max){
               max=sum;
           }
        }   
    }
    return max;
}
```

the answer should be **-6** but I got **0** why is this **happen** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems :

Firstly, max is set to 0 (`int max=0`) , all sums are negatives, therefore **0** is always greater.

Secondly, see [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3911400/7462275) to understand how to pass 2D array to a function.

(Example of code but others solutions are possible. I suppose your compiler supports VLA. Let me know if it is not the case. I have another solution)

```
#include <math.h> // To have the definition of INFINITY

int hourglassSum(int arr_rows, int arr_columns, int arr[arr_rows][arr_columns]) { //For compiler that supports VLA
    int max=-INFINITY;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<arr_rows-2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<arr_columns-2;j++){
          int sum=arr[i][j]+arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j+2]+arr[i+1][j+1]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2];
          printf("sum %d\n",sum);
           if(sum>=max){
               max=sum;
           }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

And to call it : `hourglassSum(6,6,a)`