# Pointers to arrays and 2 dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am learning about pointers and how they work in general. I have found some example code online:
https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/pointers-and-2-d-arrays/

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *p; // pointer to int
    int (*parr)[5]; // pointer to an array of 5 integers
    int my_arr[5]; // an array of 5 integers

    p = my_arr; 
    parr = my_arr;

    printf("Address of p = %u\n", p );
    printf("Address of parr = %u\n", parr );

    p++;
    parr++;

    printf("\nAfter incrementing p and parr by 1 \n\n");
    printf("Address of p = %u\n", p );
    printf("Address of parr = %u\n", parr );

    printf("Address of parr = %u\n", *parr );

    // signal to operating system program ran fine
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am having an error when debugging this code:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'int [5]' to 'int (*)[5]'  First_project_vs    C:\Users\Lukas\Desktop\VS_projects\First_project_vs\First_project_vs\First_project_vs.cpp   16
```

Perhaps someone can help me understand what is the issue here? Is the example provided code wrong?

Also, I am learning from the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuegQmMdy8M&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org

If you go to 1:48:52, You will see, that he is suggesting a similar method of declaring a pointer which I am also having issues compiling.

Can someone shed some light to me about what is wrong here? Appreciate any help

Comment: `printf("Address of p = %u\n", p );` is Undefined Behavior. you need to use `%p` for pointers. (yes, online tutorial are sometimes/often wrong and this one has multiple errors.).

Comment: Visual code suggests that the problem is with this line of code: ```parr = my_arr;```  error message:```a value of type int* cannot be assigned to an entity of type int(*)[5]```

Comment: @LukasPetrikas. Look at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3912959/7462275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or it is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the statement

```
p = my_arr;
```

the *expression* `my_arr` has type "5-element array of `int`" (`int [5]`) - since it is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it "decays" to an expression of type "pointer to `int`" (`int *`) and the address of `my_arr[0]` is assigned to `p`, which also has type `int *`:

```
p = my_arr; // int * = int *, equivalent to p = &my_arr[0]
```

Since each `my_arr[i]` has type `int`, the expression `&my_arr[i]` has type `int *`, so

```
p = &my_arr[i]; // int * = int *
```

sets `p` to point to the `i`'th element of the array.

---

However, in the expression

```
parr = my_arr; // int (*)[5] = int *
```

`parr` has type "pointer to *5-element array of* `int`", or `int (*)[5]`.  This type is not compatible with `int *`.  In this case, we need to use the unary `&` operator on `my_arr`:

```
parr = &my_arr; // int (*)[5] = int (*)[5]
```

Since `my_arr` is the operand of the unary `&` operator, the expression does *not* decay to `int *`; instead, the type of the expression is "pointer to 5-element array of `int`".

---

Now for the fun bit - let's declare a 2d array `my_2d_arr` as

```
int my_2d_arr[3][5];
```

In this case, the expression `my_2d_arr` has type "3-element array of 5-element array of `int`" and will decay to type "pointer to 5-element array of `int`".  Remember that the rule is "N-element array of `T`" (`T [N]`) => "pointer to `T`" (`T *`) - in this case, our `T` is "5-element array of `int`".  So we can write

```
parr = my_2d_arr; // int (*)[5] = int (*)[5]
```

and it will work as expected.  The address of `my_2d_arr[0]` gets assigned to `parr`.  Just like above, it's equivalent to writing

```
parr = &my_2d_arr[0];
```

The *expression* `my_2d_arr[0]` has type "5-element array of `int`" (`int [5]`) - since it's the operand of the `&` operator, the decay doesn't occur, and the type of the expression is "pointer to 5-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[5]`).

---

Here's a handy table summarizing all of the above:

```
      Expression        Type          Decays to         Equivalent expression
      ----------        ----          ---------         ---------------------
          my_arr        int [5]       int *             &my_arr[0]
         &my_arr        int (*)[5]    n/a               n/a
         *my_arr        int           n/a               my_arr[0]
       my_arr[i]        int           n/a               n/a
      &my_arr[i]        int *         n/a               n/a

       my_2d_arr        int [3][5]    int (*)[5]        &my_2d_arr[0]
      &my_2d_arr        int (*)[3][5] n/a               n/a
      *my_2d_arr        int [5]       int *             my_2d_arr[0], &my_2d_arr[0][0]
    my_2d_arr[i]        int [5]       int *             &my_2d_arr[i][0]
   *my_2d_arr[i]        int           n/a               my_2d_arr[i][0]
   &my_2d_arr[i]        int (*)[5]    n/a               n/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find the dupe, but you need to take the address of the object and assign that to the pointer. You do that with the operator &.

```
parr = &my_arr;
```

I suggest you start looking for another tutorial. This one has multiple errors. i.e. you will learn wrong things.

- For C, check [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/562377)
- For C++, check [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282)

Comment: That fixed the problem... Thanks I should probably look into different pointers tutorial in that case! Perhaps you have some recommendations?

Comment: By using the operator &, you're making `parr` access a pointer to a pointer to the array, not the array itself.

Comment: Well, in this case the array is allocated on stack, so you could access the array directly. But that aside, yes, that's what a pointer does. it points to another object. and if that object is a pointer, the pointer points to a pointer. the definition is correct in this case.

Comment: Just tried compling this with GCC: `error: invalid initializer` on the line `int *parr[10] = &arr;`

Comment: @rdbo crucial mistake. should be `int (*parr)[10] = &arr;` (or with 5 in this case)

Comment: @JHBonarius Oh, my bad, seems you're right. I still don't think it's a good idea to access this array as a reference, as you'd have to dereference it everytime you want to read from/write to it from the pointer. Useful for matrices though.

Comment: @rdbo this is just a coding example for a tutorial. However, consider using it as a function parameter. You don't want to copy the whole array, so pass a proper pointer. (maybe also look up some of the books in the links in my answer, there's definitely info on this in some of them)

Comment: `(*parr)[0] = 10`...don't forget the parentheses! And yes, that's how pointers work. (C++ will not even allow a lot of things you can do in C due to type safety).

Comment: I thought a little bit more about it, and this way seems better now. An extra dereference isn't going to hurt.

Answer (score 0):

In this assignment statement

```
parr = my_arr;
```

the left operand has the type `int ( * )[5]` while the right operand has the type `int[5]` and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another.

If you want to initialize the pointer `parr`  with the address of the array my_arr as a whole object then you have to write

```
parr = &my_arr;
```

Pay attention to that the text in these calls of printf

```
printf("Address of p = %u\n", p );
printf("Address of parr = %u\n", parr );
```

is incorrect and moreover there are used incorrect conversion specifiers. The function do not output addresses if the variables `p` and `parr`. They are trying to output stored values in these pointers.

So you have to write for example

```
printf("Address stored in p = %p\n", ( void * )p );
printf("Address stored in parr = %p\n", ( void * )parr );
```

And in the both calls there will be outputted the same value.