# How to write a square matrix multiplication function in C?

Tags: c

```
int Ma_Multiplication(int A[][], int B[][], int size){
    int C[size][size];
    for( i = 0 ; i< size ; ++i){
        for( j=0 ; j< size ; ++j){
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for( k = 0 ; k < size; ++k)
                C[i][j] = C[i][j] + (A[i][k]*B[k][j]);
                printf("%d ",C[i][j]);           
            printf("\n");
        }
}
```

I wrote this function to calculate multiplication of 2 matrices. But when I debugged, it told me this:

```
error: array type has incomplete element type 'int[]'        
    4 | int MATRIX(int A[][], int size){
      |                ^
```

Could anyone can explain this? Thank u so much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c

Comment: `A[]][]` is not a valid C syntax. The compiler has no idea how to translate it in assembler.

Comment: So how to add it ? I want to use function because i have done it with direct code.

Comment: Declare the function like `int mult(int size, int A[size][size], int B[size][size])`

Comment: Why do you need `C` to be a 2D array for if you only use it to print one item at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not allow declaration of arrays with element of incomplete type. Thus `int A[]` is ok. However, `int A[][]` is not because it's element type is `int[]` which is incomplete.

To fix I suggest fully defining the parameters using VLA types:

```
int Ma_Multiplication(int size, int A[size][size], int B[size][size]) {
  ...
}
```

If you want to keep an original ordering of parameters you must use an extension (GCC and CLANG) allowing to declare the parameters.

```
int Ma_Multiplication(int size; int A[size][size], int B[size][size], int size)
```

This extension may get mainlined into upcoming C23 standard