# Passing 2d arrays without knowing the size?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Can anyone help me? I want to pass firstMatrix, secondMatrix, and finalMatrix. So far I have this. I could make it a global variable but I still wouldnt know the actual size

```
int matrixSummation(int firstMatrix[][matrixSize],int secondMatrix[][matrixSize], int finalMatrix[][matrixSize], int matrixSize){
for(int row=0; row< matrixSize; row++){
    for(int col=0; col< matrixSize; col++){
        finalMatrix[row][col]=firstMatrix[row][col]+secondMatrix[row][col];
    }
}
}
  int main(int argc, char** argv) {


int matrixSize;

cout << "Enter size of your matrices: " <<endl;
cin >> matrixSize;

int firstMatrix[matrixSize][matrixSize];
int secondMatrix[matrixSize][matrixSize];
int finalMatrix[matrixSize][matrixSize];

cout <<"Enter numbers for the 1st matrix: "<<endl;
for(int row = 0; row < matrixSize; row++){
    for(int col=0; col< matrixSize; col++){
        cin >> firstMatrix[row][col];
    }
}

cout <<"Enter your numbers for the 2nd matrix: "<<endl;
for(int row = 0; row < matrixSize; row++){
    for(int col=0; col< matrixSize; col++){
        cin >> secondMatrix[row][col];
    }
}
matrixSummation(firstMatrix,secondMatrix,finalMatrix,matrixSize);
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @brokenfoot use of undeclared identifier 'matrixSize',    candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int [matrixSize][matrixSize]' to 'int *' for 1st argument

Comment: OK, make `matrixSize` a global.

Comment: Duplicate of [passing 2D array to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function) (C++). The accepted answer there explains your options.

Comment: @bazzargh : mm..it doesn't seem to talk about the case when a 2D array with unknows dimesions has to be passed.

Comment: @brokenfoot This question wants to leave matrixSize as a parameter (not unknown, but parameterisable), which he can't do with the style of declaration he used; I'm referring the questioner to the other answer because they show you different ways of passing the matrix, the 3rd one lets you pass the size as a parameter.

Comment: @bazzargh: Alright, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function template:

```
template<std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
int matrixSummation(int (&firstMatrix)[A][B], int (&secondMatrix)[A][B], int (&finalMatrix)[A][B])
```

so that inside your function you can access the number of rows with `A` and the number of columns with `B`, without passing sizes around.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done. At compile time, the function

```
int matrixSummation(int firstMatrix[][matrixSize],int secondMatrix[][matrixSize], int finalMatrix[][matrixSize], int matrixSize){
```

should know the matrix dimesions (atleast the columns).

See here: [Passing array with unknown size to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991057/passing-array-with-unknown-size-to-function)

---

You can make a 1D array represent your 2d array:

instead of

```
array[ROW][COL];
```

use

```
array[ROW*COL];
```

And when accessing:

```
a[r][c]; //r<5,c<5
```

Use:

```
a[r*ROW+c];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on dynamic array size for my image file as well, in the end i just pass the array using int**.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printMatrix(int** val, int row, int col)
{
    int new_val[row][col];
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            new_val[i][j] = val[i][j];
            cout<<new_val[i][j]<<" ";
        }cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"test!"<<endl;
}

int main ()
{
    int i, j, k;
    int row, col;
    row = 3;
    col = 5;
    int** array = new int*[row];
    for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = new int[col];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = k;
            k++;
            cout << array[i][j]<< " ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    printMatrix(array, row, col);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that this is not allowed in Standard C++:

```
cin >> matrixSize;
int firstMatrix[matrixSize][matrixSize];
```

Some compilers let this pass, so far; however you then run into difficulties when trying to use `firstMatrix`. For example the problem that you have had trying to pass it to a function.

In fact the reason this is not allowed in Standard C++ is that so far nobody has been able to come up with a proposal that does not run into difficulties sooner or later.

The best course of action would be to declare your arrays differently, in a way that is compatible with Standard C++.

In Standard C++, C-style arrays must have their dimension known at compile-time. Therefore you must use a different container.

---

The version that is the simplest code to write would look like:

```
vector< vector<int> > firstMatrix(matrixSize, vector<int>(matrixSize));
```

which creates a 2-D array with each dimension being `matrixSize` and then you can access it in the same way you would access a C-style array.

Importantly, you can pass `firstMatrix` to a function exactly the same way you would pass any other variable, and its sizes can be accessed via member functions of the vector, e.g. `firstMatrix.size()` is the number of rows, and `firstMatrix[0].size()` is the number of columns.

---

That version is a bit less efficient at run-time due to the fact that each row is stored in a separate allocation.  To have a contiguous storage you can write:

```
vector<int> firstMatrix(matrixSize * matrixSize);
```

Then you simulate the rows and columns within that allocation, for example the previous code's `firstMatrix[2][3]` would in this solution be `firstMatrix[2 * matrixSize + 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

The big thing here is initializing a dynamically allocated 2-D array. I recommend using "vectors," but I show a pointer approach. There is no need to pass a set value for the size to the function.

```
int[][] matrixSummation(int firstMatrix[][],int secondMatrix[][]){
    if(firstMatrix.length != secondMatrix.length 
          || firstMatrix[].length !=secondMatrix[].length)
          return NULL;

    int **finalMatrix;
    finalMatrix= new int*[firstMatrix.length]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        finalMatrix[i] = new int[firstMatrix.length]; 
        //make sure you initialize each int[]__ with proper length.
    }

    for(int row=0; row< matrixSize; row++){
        for(int col=0; col< matrixSize; col++){
            finalMatrix[row][col]=firstMatrix[row][col]+secondMatrix[row][col];
        }
    }
    return finalMatrix;
}
```